# Accumulo tserver only listens on localhost

Tags: ip-address, accumulo

When connecting to Accumulo (1.6.1) from a remote host, Zookeeper reports that the tservers are on localhost:9997.

Ex:

```
Reading reply sessionid:0x1499ab570f4001c, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 5,8  replyHeader:: 5,2814,0  request:: '/accumulo/eed8a68b-0ea4-46c7-a2fe-fcf6d8bd6ab5/tservers,T  response:: v{'localhost:9997}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to update the `$ACCUMULO_HOME/conf/{masters,monitor,slaves,gc,tracers}` files, as they indicate `localhost` by default.

See: http://accumulo.apache.org/1.6/accumulo_user_manual.html#_cluster_specification

> 11.5.3. Cluster Specification On the machine that will serve as the Accumulo master:
>
> 1.Write the IP address or domain name of the Accumulo Master to the $ACCUMULO_HOME/conf/masters file.
>
> 2.Write the IP addresses or domain name of the machines that will be TabletServers in $ACCUMULO_HOME/conf/slaves, one per line.
>
> Note that if using domain names rather than IP addresses, DNS must be
>   configured properly for all machines participating in the cluster. DNS
>   can be a confusing source of errors.